# Find a 1-1 function that maps the open unit square into $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the open interval $(0,1)$, and let $S$ be the set of points in the open unit square; that is, $S=\{(x,y): 0<x,y<1\}$.

Use the fact that every real number has a decimal expansion to produce a 1-1 function that maps $S$ into $(0,1)$.

I had a few attempts but I found duplicates inputs to the same output in my function. I have been unable to find a injective function.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a data point $(0.a_1a_2a_3...,0.b_1b_2b_3...)\in S$, we map this point to $0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3...$.

Comment: You need to say something about non uniqueness of decimal expansions.

Comment: So all numbers between $(0,1)$ has unique decimal expansion? How do we do that? Please help

Comment: .25 = .249999999999999999...

Comment: so then the solution doesn't work?